# MongoDB is it possible to update only part of the document?

Tags: database, mongodb

I have this:

```
//users collection:
{
  personal_info: {
    first_name: "John",
    address: {
      city: "New york",
      street: "A"
    }
  }
}
```

I want to make the next update with this:

```
req.body = {
  "address.street": "B"
}

db.users.update({}, {$set: req.body}, err => {
  ...
});
```

As you can see, I take the whole document and asks for mongo to update only what changed in the set.

Is this possible?

Instead Mongo takes the whole document and replace it and sets a new document:

```
{
   personal_info: {
     first_name: "John",
     address: {
       street: "B"
     }
   }
} // notice that "address.city" is gone
```

Comment: I hope it's clear, I want to tell MongoDB to update the only changed fields in the object in the document rather than replace the whole object.

Comment: Why there is `"address.street"` instead of `"personal_info.address.street"` ?

Comment: @mickl Mistake. Edited.

Answer (score 2):

You are updating the document with a different path

Your update generates a first level of address without working with the field you need.

Based on your `req.body`

```
db.users.update({}, {$set: req.body}
```

updates document like this

```
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("5c2e4872e44cfe4170bc1565"), 
    "personal_info" : {
        "first_name" : "John", 
        "address" : {
            "city" : "New york", 
            "street" : "A"
        }
    }, 
    "address" : {
        "street" : "B"
    }
}
```

since your address is inside `personal_info` field

For doing what you want, you have to specify the properly root.

```
db.sample.update({}, {$set: {"personal_info.address.street" : "B"}})
```

Comment: The properly root is can be changed. This is when user updates a resource, not all of the fields are required.. I can make a parser of his query bymyself but it's tedious and maybe MongoDB has it's own parser built in? Thats my question.

Comment: By the way with your last response I'm little confused about your issue. I think you're magnifying the problem. Writing your own  parser seems IMO an exaggerated solution. It's just an update of a document and if your root can be changed , probably you need to design your document in different way.

Comment: I just want to send an object with the key of A and tell MongoDB to update only key A rather than replacing the whole object..